# How to enable and disable Bluetooth using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, bluetooth, windows-ce, smart-device-framework

i'm currently working on bluetooth activation (**just enable and disable the bluetooth after a certain operation automatically from Windows CE version 6**)
i'm using **SmartDeviceFramework** i.e CAB file that i then install it in Windows CE

Below is my method i worked on used 
(**InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll** file for Bluetooth):

```
  private static void setBluetoothConnection()
    {
     try
       {
           if (BluetoothRadio.IsSupported == true)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth Supported", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
               BluetoothRadio radio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
               MessageBox.Show(radio.Mode.ToString(), "Before Bluetooth Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
               radio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
               // here radio.Mode works only if the Windows Device has Bluetooth enabled otherwise gives error
               MessageBox.Show(radio.Mode.ToString(), "RadioMode Discover", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
               bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
               //Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
               BluetoothDeviceInfo[] bluetoothDeviceInfo = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices();
               MessageBox.Show(bluetoothDeviceInfo.Length.ToString(), "Device Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
               foreach(BluetoothDeviceInfo device in bluetoothDeviceInfo)
               {
                 Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                 MessageBox.Show(device.DeviceName, "Device Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                 bluetoothClient.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint(device.DeviceAddress, service));
                 MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth Connected...", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                 break;
               }
             }
          else
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth Not Supported", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
          }
       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           log.Error("[Bluetooth] Connection failed", ex);
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

so i face error here :

```
BluetoothRadio radio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
radio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable; // gives error here
```

**Error** :

```
Error setting BluetoothRadio.Mode
```

The above error occurs **once** when Bluetooth is disabled in Device and the above line is executed and closes the application 
But as the application closes, and when i go to Bluetooth Manager in Mobile, the **Bluetooth is enabled**.

**my problem** :

> i have to click a button 2 times to enable button (1st when the
>   application closes with error (but Bluetooth is set ON) and 2nd to
>   search Devices in range) instead of 1 click.

**My Assumption**

> I think that there maybe some security problem when the program tries
>   to enable the Bluetooth from Mobile from OFF to Discoverable.

So is there any **Process** (**System.Digonostics; dll**) by which i can set the Bluetooth **ON** and **OFF** automatically in **WindowsMobile CE** in C#

I tried but not getting it, so could anyone help me with this or suggest any **dll** files for Bluetooth connection.

Thanks

Comment: IoT, bluetooth, and 32feet.net?  Upvote from me ; ).

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried with 32feet.net (InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll) but gets error while enabling bluetooth. Do u know where i can find Microsoft.WindowsMobile.SharedSource.Bluetooth dll ? will this dll work ? any idea

Answer (score 3):

You may find this useful:

[Bluetooth Device Development using C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/09/13/bluetooth-device-control-development-using-c.aspx)

and the download for the Windows Embedded Source Tools for Bluetooth Technology is here:

[Download](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=2913250)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: its not the solution i want...tried with Microsoft.WindowsMobile.SharedSource.Bluetooth but could not find the dll (if it exists) but thanks.

Comment: Download & Install the above then navigate to: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Windows Embedded Source Tools\   you will find the dll there ;)

Comment: The first link results in a 404 now

Comment: 2nd Link is also broken.  Now it just opens Edge Browser to the default Bing search page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what that library you're using is, so I'm not sure exactly why it is giving you that error.

Here is MSFTs documentation as to how to set the Bluetooth connection mode on a device. If you can use these DLLs you may be able to have some luck.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416244.aspx

Comment: yes i have tried this but was not successful in implementing it. my assumption the value for BthGetMode and BthSetMode is int .. i wanted RadioMode... but thanks